# Using NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey in NativeScript

Tags: ios, nativescript, icloud

In react native we have:

```
type MkdirOptions = {
  NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey?: boolean; // iOS only
};
```

What is the equivalent in NativeScript?
I need a directory under knownFolders.documents() that will not be backed-up to iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSURL.URLWithString(path).setResourceValueForKeyError(true, NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey);
```

Where `path` is complete path of your file or folder.

Comment: Thank you.
Can you elaborate on this: setResourceValueForKeyError
Why setResourceValueForKeyError and not setResourceValueForKey ?

Comment: That's not a valid Objective C method.

Comment: The name setResourceValueForKeyError seems strange and I could not find explanations about it. I will add the line you gave me to our code tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Use Typescript definitions - `nativescript-platform-declarations`

Comment: I found: setResourceValue:forKey:error: in Apple documentation.
It has colons inside and you wrote to use: setResourceValueForKeyError
I could not find it in NativeScript documentation.
What do I have to include in my TS file for this to work?

Comment: You must refer [the iOS marshalling docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/Marshalling-Overview) to understand how to convert Objective C into JS / TS. Use `nativescript-platform-declarations` plugin for intellisense support.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I will try the line you suggested. I did not understand the marshaling docs, probably because I am not familiar with Objective-C.
I take it that you know Objective-C and therefore I can assume you gave me the correct code.

Comment: I tried adding the line and I get error that NSURL is undefined.
I found no documentation in NativeScript on how to add it.